# Getting page and word counts from multiple Word files without opening them

Tags: windows, csv, command-line, ms-word

I need a list (in Windows 7) as a csv-file of Word documents in a directory showing the number of pages and words in them. I wish to use a method with which I would not have to open the files, since there are so many, but all the scripts I have found do open the file to see this information.

So, what I basically need is this list as a csv file:

[A list of files in a directory with attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imu7y.png)

Is there a sufficient way to do this, preferably with command line? I have tried with this, but am not sure is it possible to get the information needed from the files with it:

```
powershell "Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\directory\to\scan\ | ForEach-Object {$_ | add-member -name "Owner" -membertype noteproperty -value (get-acl $_.fullname).owner -passthru} | Sort-Object fullname | Select FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Length,Owner | Export-Csv -Force -NoTypeInformation c:\folder\to\directory.csv"
```

[Source](http://heuristicandrew.blogspot.lu/2014/09/write-directory-listing-to-csv-in.html)

Comment: The answer depends on the file format of the documents you want to query. Are these the old *.doc format or the docx / docm format? And are they password protected and/or encrypted?

Comment: Hi Cindy! No encryption or password protection, but I would like to know the best way to do this for the files in both new and old format.

Answer (score 0):

For Word 2007 and later you can access the Office Open XML file directly (except for password/encryption). These files are "zip packages" containing multiple XML (and sometimes binary) files that define the document content. With the exception of binaries (OLE objects, macros) the files are human-readable and the content is described in the ECMA documentation which can be downloaded from the ECMA site. The Open XML SDK can make working with these files simpler.

The information you're looking for would be stored in the file, but you need to be aware that it might not be accurate, especially the page count. This is something that's always being calculated dynamically, based on the page layout for the current printer settings. Word might not save it when the document is closed and the value saved might not apply to the next configuration on which the document is opened.

The information is saved in the Extended Properties XML part of the document; the documentation for the Open XML SDK is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.extendedproperties(v=office.14).aspx

As to the older, binary file formats you may be out of luck. The binary file format is now public, but I'm not sure it saves that information. You can find out more on MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615596(v=office.14).aspx - and there's also an "Open specifications" MSDN forum where you can ask questions about it.